# iOS - SQLite - Is there a BIT_COUNT equivalent

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, sqlite

I have a scenario where I need to count the bits (`1's` and `0's`) of the binary representation of a `BIGINT` inside my `SQLite` database. This is easily done in `SQL` with `BIT_COUNT`, but it appears to not be supported in `SQLite`.

Does anyone know of any `BIT_COUNT` equivalent in `SQLite`? I've been googling my eyes out with no luck.

I'm using this on iOS, but I don't think that really matters for this question; I'm also calling SQLite through [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, using the methods described in the [Hamming Weight wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight#Efficient_implementation).

Since sqlite will up-convert the multiplied value to a REAL in the most efficient implementation, we must use the addition-and-shifting-only implementation.

```
//types and constants used in the functions below
//uint64_t is an unsigned 64-bit integer variable type (defined in C99 version of C language)
const uint64_t m1  = 0x5555555555555555; //binary: 0101...
const uint64_t m2  = 0x3333333333333333; //binary: 00110011..
const uint64_t m4  = 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f; //binary:  4 zeros,  4 ones ...

...

//This uses fewer arithmetic operations than any other known  
//implementation on machines with slow multiplication.
//This algorithm uses 17 arithmetic operations.
int popcount64b(uint64_t x)
{
    x -= (x >> 1) & m1;             //put count of each 2 bits into those 2 bits
    x = (x & m2) + ((x >> 2) & m2); //put count of each 4 bits into those 4 bits 
    x = (x + (x >> 4)) & m4;        //put count of each 8 bits into those 8 bits 
    x += x >>  8;  //put count of each 16 bits into their lowest 8 bits
    x += x >> 16;  //put count of each 32 bits into their lowest 8 bits
    x += x >> 32;  //put count of each 64 bits into their lowest 8 bits
    return x & 0x7f;
}
```

Realized in SQLlite, this looks like:

```
SELECT a, b, (x + (x >> 32)) & 0x7f AS Distance FROM (
SELECT a, b, x + (x >> 16) AS x FROM (
SELECT a, b, x + (x >>  8) AS x FROM (
SELECT a, b, (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f AS x FROM (
SELECT a, b, (x & 0x3333333333333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x3333333333333333) AS x FROM (
SELECT a, b, x - ((x >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555) AS x FROM (

-- In my case, I'm counting the bits from an x-or.
SELECT a, b, (~(a&b))&(a|b) AS x FROM (
...
)

))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.
I think the only solution viable is to add a new column, which contains the number of 1's, set during the save and a app level function that counts the number of 1's.